# Stylelint what is syntax in css to ignore rule with no option but keep using rule with secondary options

Tags: css, disable, stylelint

I'm coding a plugin for an open source project, which has a set .stylelintrc, with the rule:
`"selector-type-no-unknown": true,`

But I am styling with ion, e.g. ion-grid {}
So thinking to add to my css, e.g.:

```
/* stylelint-disable selector-type-no-unknown -- ion styles not recognised */
ion-col.total {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
/* stylelint-enable */
```

But wouldn't it be better to instead of disabling the rule completely, add/apply a secondary option like `ignoreTypes: ["/ion/"]`?
In which case how do I do it within the css?

Or am I missing something obvious here?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In which case how do I do it within the css?

It's not possible to configure rules from within the CSS. Rules are configured within the [stylelint configuration object](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure#configuration), e.g. `.stylelintrc`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "selector-type-no-unknown": [ true, { ignoreTypes: ["/^ion-/"] } ]
  }
}
```

> But wouldn't it be better to instead of disabling the rule completely, add/apply a secondary option like `ignoreTypes: ["/ion/"]`?

If `ion-` custom type selectors are a common occurrence in the codebase, then yes it is better to use a secondary option. Otherwise, using the disable commands is more appropriate.

Comment: I understand that rules are configured within .styleintrc.  But as I wrote in the question, I don't have control over those, can only turn them off for specific instances using the [ignore code option](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/ignore-code).
So my question was specifically about the syntax in the css when using the ignore code option.

Comment: It's not possible to configure rules from within the CSS.